# Proof that $\left|\arctan (x)-\frac{π}{4}-\frac{(x-1)}{2}\right| \leq \frac{(x-1)^2}{2}$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, inequality

I'm trying to prove that, for every $x \geq 1$:

$$\left|\arctan (x)-\frac{π}{4}-\frac{(x-1)}{2}\right| \leq \frac{(x-1)^2}{2}.$$

I could do it graphically on $\Bbb R$, but how to make a formal algebraic proof?

Comment: Hint:
The remainder form of Taylor's theorem is very helpful for these kinds of questions.   Check out theorem 4 page 4 of   https://www.stewartcalculus.com/data/CALCULUS%20Early%20Transcendentals/upfiles/Formulas4RemainderTaylorSeries5ET.pdf

Answer (score 1):

We have that for $x\ge 1$

$$\arctan x-\frac{π}{4}-\frac{(x-1)}{2}\le 0 \implies \left|\arctan x-\frac{π}{4}-\frac{(x-1)}{2}\right| =\frac{π}{4}+\frac{(x-1)}{2}-\arctan x$$

then consider

$$f(x)=\frac{(x-1)^2}{2}+\arctan x-\frac{π}{4}-\frac{(x-1)}{2}\implies f'(x)=\frac1{x^2+1}+x-\frac32\ge 0$$

and since $f(1)=0$ we have that $f(x)\ge 0$ and the inequality is proved.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: For each $x >1,$ Taylor gives

$$\arctan (x)=\frac{\pi}{4}+\frac{(x-1)}{2} + \frac{\arctan'' (c_x)}{2}(x-1)^2,$$

where $1<c_x<x.$ Thus all you need to show is that $|\arctan'' (c)|\le 1$ for all $c\ge 1.$

Answer (score 0):

### Hint:

Use the Taylor expansion of $\arctan(x)$ near $1$ to the second order. And the fact that $\arctan(x)$ is concave when $x\geq1$

---

### Answer:

So the Limited Taylor expansion of $\arctan(x)$ around $1$ to the second order is given by:
$$ \arctan(x)=\frac{\pi}{4}+\frac{(x-1)}{2}-\frac{(x-1)^2}{4}+o((x-1)^2)$$
Hence, $$  \arctan(x)-\frac{\pi}{4}-\frac{(x-1)}{2}=-\frac{(x-1)^2}{4}+o((x-1)^2)$$
We can write: $$o((x-1)^2)=\frac{(x-1)^2}{2}\varepsilon(x-1),\quad\varepsilon(x-1)\xrightarrow{x\rightarrow 1}{0} $$

Then we have,\begin{align}  \arctan(x)-\frac{\pi}{4}-\frac{(x-1)}{2}&=-\frac{(x-1)^2}{4}+\frac{(x-1)^2}{2}\varepsilon(x-1)\\
&=\frac{(x-1)^2}{2}\bigg(-\frac{1}{2}+\varepsilon(x-1)\bigg)\end{align}
So when $x$ is too close to $1$ we have that $$-1<\bigg(-\frac{1}{2}+\varepsilon(x-1)\bigg)<0$$
So,
\begin{align} \left|\arctan (x)-\frac{π}{4}-\frac{(x-1)}{2}\right|&=\left| \frac{(x-1)^2}{2}\bigg(-\frac{1}{2}+\varepsilon(x-1)\bigg)\right|\\
&= \frac{(x-1)^2}{2}\bigg(\frac{1}{2}-\varepsilon(x-1)\bigg)\\
&\leq \frac{(x-1)^2}{2}\tag{$\star$}\end{align}

And since for $x\geq1$, the second derivative of $f(x)=\left|\arctan (x)-\frac{π}{4}-\frac{(x-1)}{2}\right|$ is the opposite of that of $\arctan(x)$ so $f(x)$ is convex over $[1,+\infty[$. Furthermore, the second derivative of $g(x)=\frac{(x-1)^2}{2}$ is $1$ so $g(c)$ is also convex over $[1,+\infty[$.

The first derivatives of $f$ and $g$, over $[1,+\infty[$, are:
$$ f'(x)=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{1+x^2},\quad\quad g'(x)=x-1$$
We clearly have $$ g'(x)>f'(x),\quad\forall x\geq1$$
And since $g(1)=f(1)=0$ then the result $(\star)$ holds true over $[1,+\infty[$.

Comment: The expansion results in $arctg(x) \approx \frac{\pi}{4}+ \frac{2}{1+x^2}\frac{(x-1)}{2} - \frac{2x}{(1+x^2)^2} \frac{(x-1)^2}{2}$, but then I got stuck on: $\left|arctg(x) -\frac{\pi}{4} -\frac{(x-1)}{2} \right| \approx \left| \frac{(x-1)}{2} \left( \frac{2}{1+x^2} - 1 \right)- \frac{2x}{(1+x^2)^2} \frac{(x-1)^2}{2}\right|$

Comment: We don’t need Taylor’s expansion, the inequality is trivial to prove by elementary calculus tools.

Comment: @gimusi  Yes but those tools don't give insight into how the inequality was obtained.

Comment: @zhw. That's maybe another issue! The qustion is how to prove that and not to discuss how the inequality was obtained. Anyway that perspective is an interesting to discuss that also by Taylor's. Thanks, Bye

Answer (score 0):

It is convenient to let $x=u+1$ and rewrite the inequality to be proved as a pair of inequalities:

$${u\over2}-{u^2\over2}\le\arctan(u+1)-\arctan1\le{u\over2}+{u^2\over2}$$

for $u\ge0$. Now

$$\arctan(u+1)-\arctan1=\int_1^{u+1}{dt\over1+t^2}=\int_0^u{dt\over1+(1+t)^2}=\int_0^u{dt\over2+2t+t^2}$$

while

$${u\over2}-{u^2\over2}=\int_0^u{1-2t\over2} dt\qquad\text{and}\qquad{u\over2}+{u^2\over2}=\int_0^u{1+2t\over2}dt$$

It suffices, therefore, to show that, for $t\ge0$, we have

$${1-2t\over2}\le{1\over2+2t+t^2}\le{1+2t\over2}$$

The first inequality follows from $(1-2t)(2+2t+t^2)=2-2t-3t^2\le2$; the second inequality is even easier:

$${1\over2+2t+t^2}\le{1\over2}\le{1+2t\over2}$$